# Access Violation Exception saving Bitmap

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am receiving the following exception:

Exception thrown:

```
'System.AccessViolationException' in System.Drawing.dll
```

When calling the Save function of a Bitmap. The procedure works fine the first time around, but subsequent calls throw this exception.

My application takes a single long image and vertically tiles it out into several separate images. I do this by first breaking out the whole image into bytes, then in a Parallel.For loop I generate the bitmap from a subset byte array.

```
// Generate Bitmap from width, height and bytes
private Bitmap GenerateBitmap(int width, int height, byte[] bytes)
{

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, Stride(width),
                        PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed,
                        Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bytes, 0));

    bmp.SetPalette();
    return bmp;
}
```

That is the bitmap generation routine.

Here is the loop body that calls it.

```
Parallel.For(0, tileCount, i =>
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[imageWidth * tileHeight];

    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.Length; j++)
    {
        bytes[j] = imageBytes[j + (imageWidth * (tileHeight * i))];
    }

    arr[i] = GenerateBitmap(imageWidth, tileHeight, bytes);
});
```

And here is the code elsewhere that the exception is thrown.

```
foreach(Bitmap tile in pattern.Tiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating Tile " + count);
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tile))
    {
        bmp.Save(Globals.patternOutputPath + "tile_" + count + ".png");
    }
    count += 1;
}
```

Where Tiles is a property of the pattern that calls the for loop function (which returns a list of Bitmaps).

I am assuming I'm missing some clean up somewhere in here.

Additional info: all images (input and output) are 256 (index) color format.

Edit: The comments below address the problem at hand, and I THINK I've solved the problem. I changed the GenerateBitmap routine to the following and am no longer getting this exception, but I have some more testing to do.

```
private Bitmap GenerateBitmap(int width, int height, byte[] bytes)
    {

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, bmpData.Scan0, bytes.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return bmp;

        /*Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, Stride(width),
                            PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed,
                            Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(bytes, 0));

        bmp.SetPalette();
        return bmp;*/
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the memory that byte[] array used gets garbage collected outside your control. From the remarks of that [Bitmap contructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx) *The caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the block of memory specified by the scan0 parameter. However, the memory should not be released until the related Bitmap is released.*  Your code is not living up to that part of the contract. Keep those byte arrays around or find another way to keep that memory pinned.

Comment: That Marshal.Unsafe.... was in fact unsafe.  That array is not actually pinned.  You must use GCHandle.Alloc() to pin it, its AddrOfPinnedObject() to get the IntPtr.  And you must keep it pinned for as long as you use the bitmap.  You can't call GCHandle.Free() until you called that bitmap's Dispose() method.  Pretty inconvenient but them are the rulez.  Creating the bitmap normally and copying the data into it with LockBits() is the safer and more convenient alternative.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you to the both of you.